# Parsing a JSON date works differently on iOS and Android

Tags: javascript, json, datetime

My app is returning a date string in the string format '/Date(1672869600000)/'

When I parse the above using the below JavaScript I get a result of Thu Jan 05 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time) on Android:

```
var data = '/Date(1672869600000)/';
var start = new Date(parseInt(data.substr(6)))
```

The same code resolves as on Wed Jan 04 2023 14:00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Ora Standard del Pacifico USA) Chromium on iOS.

Why is this occurring, and how can I adjust my parsing function to get the correct result?

Comment: Just a guess but could it be that both devices have a different time zone configured?

Comment: `new Date(string)`'s behaviour is implementation-dependent. Both time are same but they are using device's timezone. You need to use parser.

Comment: Thank you, this does appear to be related to the timezone on the device on which the date string is being parsed.